# How do I query a Domain Controlers NTP service from a linux box?

Tags: linux, command-line, ntp

I need to confirm that a Domain Controller is acting as a NTP time server for non windows devices and servers.  I figure there must be a command in linux that will query an NTP server and see if it is accessible and serving the right time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a linux client with ntp installed & configured to point at the Windows DC you can do;

`ntpq -pcrv` which will return all the info. If you need help to understand it please post it here and we can help.

or `ntpdate -q <ip of dc>` which will do a 1 time query of the time/date but NOT set the client.